# Standard ML: Iterative vs. Recursive

Tags: recursion, sml, ml

I'm reading through ML for the Working Programmer and am a bit confused by the author's distinction between iterative and recursive.  My understanding was that "recursive" just refers to a function that calls itself.  Any function that isn't recursive is iterative (where an iterative algorithm usually involves some kind of looping).

However, in this book, the author will say something like "luckily the obvious recursive solution is iterative."  So my understanding of these terms is definitely different from how the author is using them.

Can someone clarify where I'm misunderstanding these terms?

Thanks,
bclayman

Comment: Mostly all the techniques used in that book are recursive, some are just tail recursive - which is what the author calls iterative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterative means you can express it with a loop. However, generally speaking, a loop is just a special case of recursion. For example, in SML, the loop

```
while A do B
```

is literally defined as a syntactic abbreviation for the recursive definition

```
let fun loop() = if A then (B; loop()) else () in loop() end
```

That's why "iterative" is not understood as the opposite of "recursive", but as a special case: some recursive definitions are iterative, others are not. More specifically, it is a special case of *linear* recursion, where the recursive definition is invoked at most once.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  What might be an example of a function you can write recursively but not iteratively, then?

Comment: Something that requires at least two recursive calls, e.g. quicksort or similar divide-and-conquer algorithms. Tree traversals as well. But strictly speaking, every function can be written iteratively, as long as you are willing to manage your own stack data structure instead of using the call stack. Whether that is easier or more efficient is a different question, of course. Truly iterative functions are only those that use constant space (ruling out a stack).